# Audio streaming quality not good in datagramsocket with fixed datagram packets length in android

Tags: android, udp, audio-streaming, audio-recording, datagram

Am streaming audio through datagrampackets using datagramsockets for telephonic conversation. I can able to hear audio from other end. But Other end can't hear my audio.

Here data packets are fixed to 340byte. First 20 bytes have some value for connection establishment, source address destination address etc. The next 320 byte has audio data. Here audio data are always fixed to 320byte.

```
    private static final int SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 20;
    private static final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2;
    private static final int BUF_SIZE = SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_SIZE * 2; //1600Bytes

    // the audio recording options
    private static final int RECORDING_RATE = 8000; // Hertz
    private static final int CHANNEL = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;//16
    private static final int FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;//2


    AudioRecord  audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDING_RATE, CHANNEL, FORMAT, BUF_SIZE * 10);
```

//audio transmitting thread

```
        @Override
        public void run() {


            long seq=0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];

            WiphoneProp callProp=new WiphoneProp();
            callProp.setOpCode(WiPhonePacket.OpCodes.Call.getValue());//1 byte
            callProp.setOperand(WiPhonePacket.OperandCodes.Talk.getValue());//1 byte
            callProp.setSelfState(0);//1 byte
            callProp.setCallId(1);//1 byte

            callProp.setCheckSum(BitConverter.checkSum(deviceSignature.getSignatureData(),0,deviceSignature.getSignatureData().length));//4 byte

            try {

                int offset=0;
                audioRecorder.startRecording();
                while (mic) {
                    // Capture audio from the mic and transmit it

                    try {
                        callProp.setWiphoneId(ByteBuffer.wrap(getBroadcastQuadIp().getAddress()).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());//4 byte
                        callProp.setClientId(ByteBuffer.wrap(getLocalIp().getAddress()).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());//4 byte
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    callProp.setSequence(seq);//4 byte

                    byte[] buff=new byte[320];

                    audioRecorder.read(buffer, offset, 320);

                    System.arraycopy(buffer,offset,buff,0,buff.length);
                    callProp.setVoice(buff);//320 byte

                    byte[] voice = callProp.ToBuffer();

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(voice, voice.length, InetAddress.getByName(deviceSignature.getDeviceIP()), WIPHONEPORT);
                    commonSoc.send(packet);

                    offset+=320;
                    if(offset>=1600){
                        offset=0;
                    }
                    seq++;
                }
                // Stop recording and release resources
                audioRecorder.stop();
                audioRecorder.release();
                mic = false;
            }
           /* catch(InterruptedException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
                mic = false;
            }*/
            catch(SocketException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "SocketException: " + e.toString());
                mic = false;
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString());
                mic = false;
            }
            catch(IOException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
                mic = false;
            }
        }
```

**now my audio buffer size is 1600byte.**
**There is no audio in other end.**

I referred [this](https://github.com/DeanThomson/android-udp-audio-chat/blob/master/src/hw/dt83/udpchat/AudioCall.java)

This is my c# code to get audio streaming with 320 byte

```
  CaptureDevicesCollection captureDeviceCollection = new CaptureDevicesCollection();

                DeviceInformation deviceInfo = captureDeviceCollection[0];

                capture = new Capture(deviceInfo.DriverGuid);

                short channels = 1; //Stereo.
                short bitsPerSample = 16; //16Bit, alternatively use 8Bits.
                int samplesPerSecond = 8000;//Default: 22050; //11KHz use 11025 , 22KHz use 22050, 44KHz use 44100 etc.

                //Set up the wave format to be captured.
                waveFormat = new WaveFormat();
                waveFormat.Channels = channels;
                waveFormat.FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm;
                waveFormat.SamplesPerSecond = samplesPerSecond;
                waveFormat.BitsPerSample = bitsPerSample;
                waveFormat.BlockAlign = (short)(channels * (bitsPerSample / (short)8));
                waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond = waveFormat.BlockAlign * samplesPerSecond;

                captureBufferDescription = new CaptureBufferDescription();
                captureBufferDescription.BufferBytes = waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 5; //Approx 200 milliseconds of PCM data.
                captureBufferDescription.Format = waveFormat;

                playbackBufferDescription = new BufferDescription();
                playbackBufferDescription.BufferBytes = waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 5;
                playbackBufferDescription.Format = waveFormat;
                playbackBuffer = new SecondaryBuffer(playbackBufferDescription, device);

                bufferSize = captureBufferDescription.BufferBytes;
```

//// Logic for getting 320 byte audio data

```
    try
                {
                    //The following lines get audio from microphone and then send them 
                    //across network.
                    captureBuffer = new CaptureBuffer(captureBufferDescription, capture);
                    CreateNotifyPositions();
                    int blockSize = bufferSize / 10;
                    int halfBuffer = bufferSize / 2;
                    captureBuffer.Start(true);
                    //bool readFirstBufferPart = true;
                    int offset = 0;
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(halfBuffer);
                    bStop = false;
                    uint seq = 0;
                    while (!bStop)
                    {
                        autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                            }));
                        offset = (int)(((seq + 5) % 10) * blockSize);
                        halfBuffer = blockSize;
                        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        captureBuffer.Read(offset, memStream, halfBuffer, LockFlag.None);
                        //readFirstBufferPart = !readFirstBufferPart;
                        //offset = readFirstBufferPart ? 0 : halfBuffer;
                        byte[] dataToWrite = memStream.GetBuffer();
                        var voicePacket = new WiPhonePacket
                        {
                            OpCode = (byte)WiPhonePacket.OpCodes.Call,
                            Operand = (byte)WiPhonePacket.OperandCodes.Talk,
                            SelfState = 0,
                            CallId = 1,
                            WiPhoneId = broadcastIp,
                            ClientId = localIp,
                            CheckSum = Helpers.General.CalculateChecksum(Configurations.Signature.SignatureData, 0, Configurations.Signature.SignatureData.Length),
                            Sequence = seq++
                        };
                        voicePacket.SetVoice(dataToWrite);
                        var voiceBuffer = voicePacket.ToBuffer();
                        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Configurations.Signature.DeviceIP), 2739);
                        clientSocket.SendTo(voiceBuffer, ep);
                        //udpClient.Send(dataToWrite, dataToWrite.Length, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 2739);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VoiceChat-Send ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    captureBuffer.Stop();
                    captureBuffer.Dispose();
                    captureBuffer = null;
                    autoResetEvent.Dispose();
                    autoResetEvent = null;
                    notify.Dispose();
                    notify = null;
                    //Increment flag by one.
                    nUdpClientFlag += 1;
                    //When flag is two then it means we have got out of loops in Send and Receive.
                    //while (nUdpClientFlag != 2)
                    //{ }
                    //Clear the flag.
                    nUdpClientFlag = 0;
                    //Close the socket.
                    //udpClient.Close();
                }




private void CreateNotifyPositions()
        {
            try
            {
                autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

                notify = new Notify(captureBuffer);

                BufferPositionNotify[] nots = new BufferPositionNotify[10];
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var bufferPositionNotify1 = new BufferPositionNotify();
                    bufferPositionNotify1.Offset = (i + 1) * (bufferSize / 10) - 1;
                    bufferPositionNotify1.EventNotifyHandle = autoResetEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

                    nots[i] = bufferPositionNotify1;
                }

                notify.SetNotificationPositions(nots);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VoiceChat-CreateNotifyPositions ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I see your comment "Capture audio from the mic" but I don't see the corresponding code with e.g. read(). Did I miss something?

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger Thank you the response. Its copy paste mistake. I updated my post pls check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for adding the missing part of your source. This was very useful as it contains the most obvious bug:

```
    if(i==0){
        bytes_read   = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, 319);
        System.arraycopy(buffer,0,buff,0,buff.length);
        callProp.setVoice(buff);//320 byte
    }else{
        bytes_read   = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 320, 639);
        System.arraycopy(buffer,320,buff,0,buff.length);
        callProp.setVoice(buff);//320 byte
    }
```

`audioRecorder.read()` has the number of bytes to read as the 3rd argument (and not the index of the last element of the array to be written). So you should change the code to:

```
    if(i==0){
        bytes_read   = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, 320);
        System.arraycopy(buffer,0,buff,0,buff.length);
        callProp.setVoice(buff);//320 byte
    }else{
        bytes_read   = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 320, 320);
        System.arraycopy(buffer,320,buff,0,buff.length);
        callProp.setVoice(buff);//320 byte
    }
```

After that the sound quality should be much better but don't expect too much: your sample rate is only 8kHz which means that the highest possible frequencies are lower that 4kHz which is about old telephone quality.

Comment: thank you. before buffer size was 640byte so i send audio data in two part but now i changed to 1600byte(halfBuffer) as in C#. Anyway i ll try this and let u know the status.

Comment: actually buffer size was differ by device some device has 640 some has 1024. so i created constant buffer with 1600byte and reading audio data with 320byte fixed. I updated my code. pls check it

Comment: Better. And what about the sound, now?

Comment: There is no sound now

Comment: I don't see that `mic` in is set to `true` for the line `while (mic) {`

Comment: i just declared it globally it coming inside the loop don't worry about that. Could you able to find anything from new code?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue as following

```
private static final int SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 20; // Milliseconds
private static final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2; // Bytes
private static final int BUF_SIZE = SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_SIZE * 2; 


private static final int RECORDING_RATE = 8000; // Hertz
private static final int CHANNEL = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;//16
private static final int FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;//2


audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
            RECORDING_RATE, CHANNEL, FORMAT,BUF_SIZE*10);


@Override
            public void run() {
                // Create an instance of the AudioRecord class
                long seq=0;
                int offset=0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];

                try {
                    // Create a socket and start recording
                    Log.i(TAG, "Packet destination: " + deviceSignature.getDeviceIP()+ " "+BUF_SIZE);
                    audioRecorder.startRecording();
                    while (mic) {
                        // Capture audio from the mic and transmit it

                        WiphoneProp callProp=new WiphoneProp();
                        callProp.setOpCode(WiPhonePacket.OpCodes.Call.getValue());
                        callProp.setOperand(WiPhonePacket.OperandCodes.Talk.getValue());
                        callProp.setSelfState(0);
                        callProp.setCallId(1);

                        callProp.setCheckSum(BitConverter.checkSum(deviceSignature.getSignatureData(),0,deviceSignature.getSignatureData().length));
                        try {
                            callProp.setWiphoneId(ByteBuffer.wrap(getBroadcastQuadIp().getAddress()).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());//broadcast ip or wiphone ip
                            callProp.setClientId(ByteBuffer.wrap(getLocalIp().getAddress()).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());//device ip or local ip
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        callProp.setSequence(seq);

                        byte[] buff=new byte[320];

                        audioRecorder.read(buffer, offset, buff.length);

                        System.arraycopy(buffer,offset,buff,0,buff.length);

                        callProp.setVoice(buff);//320 byte
                        byte[] voice = callProp.ToBuffer();


                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(voice, voice.length, InetAddress.getByName(deviceSignature.getDeviceIP()), WIPHONEPORT);
                        commonSoc.send(packet);

                        seq++;
                        offset+=320;
                        if(offset>=1600){
                            offset=0;
                        }


                    }
                    // Stop recording and release resources
                    audioRecorder.stop();
                    audioRecorder.release();
                    mic = false;
                }
               /* catch(InterruptedException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }*/
                catch(SocketException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "SocketException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }
                catch(UnknownHostException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }
                catch(IOException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }
            }
```